# Cartesian product of two odd and even numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I just started learning Calculus and I'm interested in how to write the cartesian product of $A=\{ 2n\mid n \in \Bbb N \}$ and $B=\{2n+1\mid n \in\Bbb  N \}$ sets?

Comment: It would be helpful if those voting to close could tell the OP how this question can be improved. I mean, the usual cry of "what have you tried?" doesn't really make sense here (although "Have you looked in your book for some examples?" does make sense, which is related).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\times B = \{(2n, 2m+1)\mid n\in \mathbb{N}, m\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is one way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$A \times B = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{N}^2: (x = 2n) \land (y = 2r+1) \land (n,r \in \mathbb{N}) \}$$

That's one way to write it.